# Queryset is evaluated when sliced?

Tags: django, django-queryset

In django queryset doc(https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/), it says "Internally, a QuerySet can be constructed, filtered, ***sliced***, and generally passed around without actually hitting the database. No database activity actually occurs until you do something to evaluate the queryset." And then, it says "You can evaluate a QuerySet in the following ways: Iteration / ***Slicing*** / . . ." .

So, my question is "whether Queryset is evaluated when sliced" .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The full paragraph explains when slicing will evaluate the queryset, and when not (emphasis mine):

> - Slicing. As explained in Limiting QuerySets, a QuerySet can be sliced, using Python’s array-slicing syntax. Slicing an unevaluated QuerySet usually returns another unevaluated QuerySet, but Django will **execute the database query if you use the “step” parameter** of slice syntax, and will return a list. Slicing a QuerySet that has been evaluated also returns a list.

Django will only evaluate the queryset when you use the step parameter, for example `queryset[::2]`, since this can't be translated into an SQL query. In other cases, slicing an unevaluated queryset will return another unevaluated queryset, and Django will add a `LIMIT` and/or `OFFSET` to the query.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It cofuses me a long time. > <

Comment: Will a `return` from a view or API endpoint also evaluate the QuerySet? I read the documentation and it is not explicit about it, but it would make sense since on these two situations the next step is the template/application layer.